# Select the same name with different [number]

Tags: r

I have column names like the following plot
[image]

Can I select all `alpha` one time instead of typing `alpha[1], alpha[2]...alpha[9]`?

How can I put in the following codes to let R know I need results of all alpha?

```
t_alpha <- mcmc_trace(mcmc,pars="alpha")
```

Comment: If `mcmc` is your dataframe then `mcmc[grep('alpha', names(mcmc))]` will select columns with `'alhpa'` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df %>% select(matches("^alpha"))`

#   alpha.1. alpha.10.
# 1       55        43
# 2       97        20
# 3       80        84
# 4       24        60
# 5       27        21
# 6       98        70
```